# Angular UI Router controllers instantiated multiple times - Direct route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have a parent / child route set up, and everything works great when I change the state in code using state.go().  The problem arises when I try to go directly to the child route using only a URL.  When I do this, the controllers get initialized multiple times.

Here is my app.js

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "Views/home.html",
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('ticketsMaster', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "Views/tickets-master.html",
        url: "^/performances?featureCode&theatreId",
        controller: 'TicketsMasterController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .state('ticketsMaster.performances', {
        url: "^/performances?featureCode&theatreId",
        templateUrl: "Views/performances.html",
        controller: 'PerformancesController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
```

home.html is my master page where I have my ui-view

I also have another ui-view on my tickets-master.html where this loads my child views (performances).

When going directly to `/performances?featureCode=1111&theatreId=1` it loads my `TicketsMasterController`, and Performances controller 2 or 3 times.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the point of routing them to ```"^/performances?featureCode&theatreId",``` in two different states?

Comment: that was a genuine question, do you have to declare a url in every state to load a template?

Comment: That is a good question - I only put it there because I can only get it off of the ticketsMaster state.  If I put it only on the ticketsMaster.performances state, I am not able to see them at all.  I get rid of the url completely on the master one, and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372

> add this line to app.config:
>
> `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')`
>
> and include this line in the head of index.html:
>
> `<base href="/">`